# Parse xml with Ansible

Tags: xml, ansible, xml-parsing

i would add some of children of an element in `xml` file with `lxml` module

I hade some probleme of adding it on the right place, this is some example of what i would do:

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<businesss>
<business type="bar">
        <name>walid</name>
     <beers>
       <beer>Rochefort 10</beer>
       <beer>St. Bernardus Abbot 12</beer>
       <beer>Schlitz</beer>
       <beer>walid</beer>
     <rating subjective="walid">10</rating>
     </beers>
   <website>
     <mobilefriendly/>
     <address>http://tastybeverageco.com</address>
   </website>
 </business>
 <business type="maar">
   <name>Tasty Beverage Co.</name>
     <beers>
       <beer>Rochefort 10</beer>
       <beer>St. Bernardus Abbot 12</beer>
       <beer>Schlitz</beer>
    </beers>
   <rating subjective="true">10</rating>
   <website>
     <mobilefriendly/>
     <address>http://tastybeverageco.com</address>
   </website>
 </business>
 </businesss>
```

wehn i try to add new childrens, it always add it in the last `business` quotes (`business type="maar"`)

Here is my `yaml` for adding it on the firt `business` quote (`business type="bar"`):

```
- name: Add child
     xml:
             path: ./test.xml
             xpath: /businesss/business/@type[texte()="bar]/beers                 add_children:
                     - beer: alyne
                     - beer: mira
```

Or somthing like this. Can anyone have an idea please?

Answer (score 0):

After many tries, i found the solution, here is my new `yaml` file:

```
- name: Add child
     xml:
             path: ./test.xml
             xpath: /businesss/business[@type="bar"]/beers ##Add child beer with business type bar 
              
             add_children:
               - beer: "new child"
```

And it adding it in the `business bar`

For anyone who need it.